# Access VBA - can’t figure out how to reference my subform control in the main form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

When user updates textbox in subform want textbox in main form to update but I can’t seem to figure out how to call my subform textbox in the main form. I know it must be something simple...I just can’t seem to figure it out.

I tried

```
    Me.subfrmAB.textbox1.Text
```

I tried

```
    Me.subfrmAB.Form.textbox1.Text
```

Just not sure how to call it

Edit:
This is what I’m trying to do (on main form Form_Current event)

```
   If IsNull(Me.subfrmAB.Form.Controls(subfrmtxtbx1)) Or IsNull(Me.subfrmAB.Form.Control(subfrmtxtbx2)) Or IsNull(Me.subfrmAB.Form.Control(subfrmtxtbx3))Then 
      Me.textboxAB.Text = “Phase 1” 
   End If
```

But it won’t trigger on the form current event.

I also tried

```
        If IsNull(Me.subfrmAB.Form.Controls(subfrmtxtbx1)) Or IsNull(Me.subfrmAB.Form.Control(subfrmtxtbx2)) Or IsNull(Me.subfrmAB.Form.Control(subfrmtxtbx3))Then 
            Me.textboxAB.Value= “Phase 1” 
        End If
```

But then I get an error stating that Me.textboxAB.Value =0

Comment: Is this code being called on that text box update? or from the main form?

Comment: [Forms: Refer to Form and Subform properties and controls](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm)

Comment: Don't use Text property. Need Value which is default for data controls. Why need to replicate value between forms? Is this storing same data in two tables? What event is code in?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav sorry for replying late. The code is being called on the main form

Comment: @June7 no ultimately my subform is a timeline. I want the textbox on the main form show what phase a user is in depending on the what they have filled out on the timeline (subform)

Comment: @June7 the code is on the form current event of the main form

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I updated my code maybe this makes more sense now. Thank you for the reference

Comment: You say you want to set a textbox but code references a combobox. OnCurrent will not trigger unless main form navigates to another record, won't just because textbox on subform is edited.

Comment: @HansUp sorry it’s not actually an error. The code runs, but instead of Phase 1 appearing on the main form textbox 0 shows up instead.  So I put a breakpoint on the if line to try and debug my code. When I hovered over the break point a pop up appeared stating Me.textboxAB.Value = 0. And it’s a textbox not combobox sorry, I updated code

Comment: @June7 sorry you are correct it is a textbox I have updated code.  
 And the event is on Form_Current. Right so when the main form navigates from one record to the next the textbox should update right? But 0 shows up on every record.

Comment: @HansUp I think access is disregarded it. But if I use .text instead of .value then I get “you can’t reference a property or method for a control unless the control has the focus.

Comment: .Text only works when control has focus. Use .Value (don't even have to type it since it is default for data controls). The code should take value from whatever subform record has focus. Works for me. You might have to post to a forum that facilitates attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: Also, VBA is not needed. Expression in textbox can reference subform. However, what you are attempting doesn't really make sense. Why would you want to pull edited value from subform only after navigating on main form? And navigating subform means a different value will be pulled next time navigating main form.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Me.subfrmAB.Form.Controls("textbox1").Text
```

Plus, Andre has also provided a great reference for Forms and Subforms - The Access Web by Dev Ashish. I've used that to track down some of these form/subform reference issues.

Comment: This helped, I don’t get an error but now my event won’t trigger. I added some updated code to show my issue. Thank you for your help